# How do you link images set as backgrounds in your CSS file?

Tags: magento2, css, media-images

**The situation:**
My custom CSS files are located inside the web/css directory and the page is accessing these files just fine. I can see my styles in effect as they are being loaded.

**The problem:**
The only problem I am experiencing is that there are several div blocks that I have set a background image for and these images aren't showing up. I am almost certain this is due to the location structure.

How do I properly reference the images located in my web/images folder to my css file (located in web/css)?

Comment: Can you show us the code you have linking to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to reference the images would be using Unix-style directory symbols: `../images/your-image.png`. Ideally, you'd put styles like this in the HTML head or perhaps inline them. Either way, the ideal would be to output the path using `$block->getViewFileUrl()`.

Comment: Your answer was totally right. I initially did just this but accidentally had ../image/my-image.png instead of /images/